# Is there some relation between $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ and $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}(t)}/\mathbb{Q}(t))$

Tags: galois-theory

Is there some relation between $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ and $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}(t)}/\mathbb{Q}(t))$ ?

Are these two groups isomorphic as I remember I have seen it somewhere but I am not sure.

Comment: My guess would be that the former is a subgroup of the latter in the obvious way. The image of that embedding then misses out on the fun you get by looking at automorphisms of, say, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt t)/\Bbb{Q}(t)$ extended to the algebraic closure $\overline{\Bbb{Q}(t)}$.